# How to have Image-Saving Function for Images Normalized with [0,1] and [0,255]?

Tags: python-3.x, function, pytorch

I have a collection of images, with some being normalized within the range of [0,1], and others within the range of [0,255]. I don't know about when input images is normalized in [0,1] form and when the other form. That's why I'm trying to write a function that support both.

In other words, I would like to create a function that can support both cases, where I can provide an image to the function and have it saved accordingly. Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: How about you do something like `if max(image)>1: do something; else: do something else`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this answers your question but it is what I thought of doing. You can check the range of image and convert them to a standard form. This is what I mean:

```
min_val = np.min(image)
max_val = np.max(image)

if min_val >= 0 and max_val <= 1:
        # Image normalized in [0, 1] range
        image = (image * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    elif min_val >= 0 and max_val <= 255:
        # Image already in [0, 255] range
        image = image.astype(np.uint8)
    else:
        # Error
```

Hope this helps.